# Feel strongly (about something)

Tags: idioms

> In his book, “Surely You’re Joking, Mr. Feynman!”, he recalls that he ‘felt very strongly’ after he returned to his normal life. He goes on to say that ‘fortunately’, atomic bombs had been useless for ‘almost forty years’ at the time. Feynman did not generally comment on his opinions on the ethical dilemmas arising as the result of the atomic Hiroshima and Nagasaki bombing.
> ([Source](https://ysjournal.com/other/richard-feynman-and-the-manhattan-project/))

I'm a bit confused by this "feeling strongly". It seems to suggest that one has a clear opinion about something, but it's unclear which way that goes; is it positive or negative? How should I read "feeling strongly" about something?

Comment: It seems very strange that even when reading / hearing it in the full context, you *still* don't know whether Feynman strongly approved *or disapproved* of the subject matter. Please provide a link to that full context so we can understand how that might be possible.

Comment: Usually, you feel strongly something or about something, meaning that you have firm sensation about something. In that case, he perhaps thought he was was very strong after after he returned to his normal life.

Comment: What's the full context?

Comment: Fairly obviously, given Feynman's use of  ***fortunately*** above, we can assume he had a strongly ***negative*** opinion of nuclear weapons. But the text does go on to say that by and large he kept his opinions to himself, and helped to develop them. But surely this is just common sense - it's not really about the fact that this information is implicit in the *English* text above. I'm guessing all languages have the equivalent of "fortunately" here, and it woulld always carry the same implication regarding Feynman's attitude to the subject.

Comment: I suggest you post on History SE or somewhere else if you want to know Feynman's opinions of nuclear weapons. Or, like, Google it?

Comment: @Stuart -- It's not Feynman's opinion in particular I'm interested in; my question is about the idiom.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd class ***to feel strongly*** as an "idiom" - but putting that aside, the expression is "agnostic" as to whether the strong feelings are positive or negative in relation to the subject matter.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I suspect either a typo missed by proofreaders, or an OCR error if the OP is quoting from an e-book.

Comment: The quote looks like it could just be an error.  Usually we'd expect: **he "felt very strongly about it".** - to feel strongly about something is an expression. It's meaning is quite literal, so I wouldn't class this as an idiom.  It means to have strong feelings about something.

Comment: @BillyKerr - maybe he meant that he felt [things] strongly [then, compared to later in his life]?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - yes, sorry I just saw your answer. Sounds entirely reasonable. So, text in the OPs link is basically a mangled misquote.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its about a quote in an article that appears to be a misquote.

Comment: @BillyKerr - the text quoted by the OP is **exactly** as in my e-book edition of Feynman's book.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey The quote is truncated though. "I can’t understand it any more, but I felt very strongly then." - the context is important here I think, and it's missing from the quote, so it looks quite odd/out of place. The quote itself might even be a misquote - as you say, a missing **it** is entirely possible, or perhaps it was just elided in speech?

Comment: @BillyKerr - what is truncated? What I quoted in my answer below is an exact copy-and-paste from the e-book.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I mean the quote at the link provided by the OP, which is simply "felt very strongly". It's not the full quote. Feynman's actual text contains much more context. It's like cutting out a few words from a sentence, and expecting them still to make sense.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Why delete your excellent answer?

Comment: @gotube - now restored. I was doubtful about my interpretation. It could have no typo, and mean that he felt [things] strongly [then, compared to later in his life].

Answer (score 2):

If it is this section (last two paragraphs of the section titled 'Los Alamos from Below' in Part 3) then I suspect there should be the word 'it' between 'felt' and 'strongly'. His first impression was a strange one ... [and] he felt **it** [the impression] very strongly.

> I returned to civilization shortly after that and went to Cornell to
> teach, and my first impression was a very strange one. **I can’t
> understand it any more, but I felt very strongly then**. I sat in a
> restaurant in New York, for example, and I looked out at the buildings
> and I began to think, you know, about how much the radius of the
> Hiroshima bomb damage was and so forth…How far from here was 34th
> Street?…All those buildings, all smashed—and so on. And I would go
> along and I would see people building a bridge, or they’d be making a
> new road, and I thought, they’re crazy, they just don’t understand,
> they don’t understand. Why are they making new things? It’s so
> useless.
>
> But, fortunately, it’s been useless for almost forty years now, hasn’t
> it? So I’ve been wrong about it being useless making bridges and I’m
> glad those other people had the sense to go ahead.

*'Surely You’re Joking, Mr. Feynman!' - e-book of 1997 Norton edition*